# Creating a BAT to lopp directories and 7zip them

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, zip, windows-task-scheduler

I a have a bunch of folders from my projects under `C:\Projects`, and they are a lot.

While I can throw a task scheduler to robocopy the folder to `B:\Backups\Projects\`, having to 7zip (or just zip) them, one by one, is kind of tedious, specially if I create a new project folder. I do this just for simplicity, as it is more quick compress 1000 Project Files to 1 file rather than copying them.

I can bear the burden to automatically 7zip the Project Folder even if I have not touched it, but if there is no software to do it, a BAT should suffice.

Comment: We are not a script writing service here at Super User. What have you tried so far? Personally, I have done something very similar several years ago, but unfortunately, I did not keep the code. My script ran a Robocopy job with verbose entries, and then used 7zip to package the log files. Another script could unpack the logs for verification, and then delete the unpacked logs when verification/inspection was completed.

Comment: [How can I create a batch job (.bat) that zip a folder?](//superuser.com/q/724910)